# if $X$ = number of planes that arrive in an hour, what is $E[X(1-X)]$

Tags: statistics, proof-verification

other information, if needed

suppose that airplanes arrive at an airport according to a Poisson process a rate of 3 per minute

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of your specific problem, notice that:

$\mathbb{E}[X(1-X)]=\mathbb{E}[X-X^2]= \mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[X^2]$

And that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=Var(X)-\big( \mathbb{E}[X] \big)^2$. And for most known distributions it is a simple matter of looking what the variance and the expectation are.